# How to display the number or rows that belong to a category for every category in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of video categories and a table of video recordings. The columns in video categories are id and cname and in video recordings there is a category column. I want to show how many video recordings belong to each category.

I have tried

```
select vc.cname, count(*) as catcount
from video_categories vc, video_recordings vr
where vc.cname = vr.category
group by vc.id
```

but that only returns the number of recordings for the first category where the id is 0.
I need them to display all of them.

I created the tables like this

```
Video_Recordings (
recording_id,
director,
title,
category,
image_name,
duration,
rating,
year_released,
price,
stock_count
);

Video_Categories (
id,
name
);

Video_Actors (
id,
name,
recording_id
);
```

with the correct data types and then i loaded them with

```
Load Data local Infile
' D:/files...' into table
video_recodrings fields terminated by '\t' lines terminated by '\n';
```

when I do that and check the tables the tables are correct.

Comment: group by the right thing. count the right thing. and don't use implicit joins.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you want number of rows by category,right then group by **group by vc.cname**

```
select vc.cname, count(*) as catcount
from video_categories vc
inner join video_recordings vr on vc.cname = vr.category
group by vc.cname
```

Comment: When I do that it still only shows for 1 category when there are 6

Comment: There are no trailing spaces

Comment: plz add your table structure with sample data Because I don't think its a query problem

Comment: I added my table structures

Answer (score 0):

You must group them by vc.name

`select vc.cname, count(*) as catcount
from video_categories as vc, video_recordings as vr
where vc.cname = vr.category
group by vc.name`

Answer (score 0):

Your query is working fine, just one small change is required. Check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e060/1

Answer (score 0):

You are probably matching the wrong column against `Video_Recordings.category`. I may be wrong but the fact that only `id = 0` is returned implies to me that the `category` column is an integer and is a reference to `Video_Categories.id` (rather than to `Video_Categories.name`).

Therefore, change your query according to the following:

```
select vc.cname, count(*) as catcount
from video_categories vc, video_recordings vr
where vc.id = vr.category
group by vc.id
;
```